# A problem about the density of weighted-$L^2$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

A Dirichlet form is a non-negative closed quadratic form $\mathcal E$ with domain $\mathcal F\subseteq L^2(X,\mu)$ which satisfies the \textit{Markov property}, namely, $u\in \mathcal F$ implies
 $\bar u =(u\vee 0)\wedge 1\in \mathcal F$ and $\mathcal E(\bar u,\bar u)\le \mathcal E(u,u)$.

Let $(X,d)$ be a bounded metric space, $\mu$ be a positive finite Borel measure on $(X,d)$, $(\mathcal E,\mathcal F)$ be a Dirichlet form on $L^2(X,\mu)$, and
 $A$ be the associated non-negative self-adjoint operator.
Assume that the Sobolev inequality holds for some $q:=2\alpha/(\alpha-2)>2$, i.e., there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
  \begin{equation}
    \|u\|_{L^q(X,\mu)}\le c\mathcal E(u,u)^{1/2}\quad\text{for all } u\in \mathcal F,
  \end{equation}and $W\in L^{\alpha'/2}(X,\mu)$ for some $\alpha'>\alpha$. Combining the Sobolev inequality above and H\"older inequality, we obtain that $\mathcal F\subseteq L^2(X,|W|\,d\mu)$. I want to know whether if $\mathcal F$ is dense in $L^2(X,|W|d\mu)$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{L^2(X,|W|d\mu)}$-norm.

Comment: Without further assumptions, you could have $\mathcal{F} = \{0\}$, hence, it cannot be dense.

Comment: No,  it is unposible that $\mathcal {F}=\{0\}$.  In fact, since $（\mathcal E,\mathcal F）$  is Dirichlet  form on $L^2(X,\mu)$,  $\mathcal F$ is dense in  $L^2(X,\mu)$.